# Should I use angular for a keyword/product aggregator website?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, angularjs

I am developing a website where users can search for products using keywords. The one of the main functions is searching and showing the search results. Each search result (product) clicks onto a detail page (which will be deleted in 2 weeks +)

What I'v Done

1. Developed the UI/Javascript for the website.
2. All product components in the html/css are reusable

So all of the basic stuff is done. Now I'm focusing on AJAX and maybe Angular depending on your opinions as well.

My partner is building the backend in Node. He told me he will send search results in JSON and ill have to use AJAX to grab it. So far I'v learned how to store the JSON object in the user's localStorage (local).

Now I can't wrap my head around how I'm going to transfer the data and display a certain number of products on the page etc..

I have some pieces but not the details.

If you can help me the areas I'm lacking that will be great, thank you.

Comment: You can easily parse the JSON and create directives to display your items .Try learning more about directives in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Google list:

- `ng-repeat` to iterate through collection
- `Angular Directives` to create reusable DOM
- `ng-include` if you have to display inline details
- `ng-if` to determinate functionality for above (not `ng-show` coz it have troubles in IE9-)
- `ui-router` to create separate details "states" (aka pages)
- `$state` to translate through application
- `$stateParams` to determinate `id` of products to display on details page

About AJAX and JSONs responses that you will acquire:

```
{
    items: [{ id:0, ... }], //collection of products
    meta: {
       totalPagesCount: '100',
       totalItemsCount: '1000'
       itemsPerPage: '10',
       currentPage: '1', 
    }
}
```

[Power that let you adapt to anything](http://json-schema.org/)

[Power that let you to find anything](https://dzone.com/articles/common-rest-design-pattern)

Obviously you will create two directives and one controller:

1. Directive for items
2. Directive for paging
3. Controller to serve the page handling your input that will send requests for collection with keyword as GET parameter and translate updated data to directives
4. Service that will do business logic as `$http.get()` with deserialization (if needed), storing information (if you gonna cache something) etc.

Passing in `ng-model` of your directives appropriate values of collection, pagination etc will let you avoid writing `$watch` and business logic inside of controller.

Keep everything simple, clear and [paterned](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html).